# Speeding up Ruby script startup in Windows or Cygwin

Tags: windows, ruby, cygwin, performance

I've got a ruby script which takes about 30 seconds to startup. It takes that much because it tries to load all libraries and stuff.

When I do `ruby.exe -v` it's instant.

I don't want to touch the original ruby script, which is not written by me.

What are the tricks to speed this process up?

- Can I precompile it?
- Can I precache all of these files?

I need to do this under Windows or Cygwin.

**UPDATE :**

- Scripts is quite slow in Linux/Mac as well, this condition is not specific to Windows.
- This is normal ruby 1.8.7 (similar speed in other ruby versions)
- Main bottleneck is loading so many libraries (I removed unrequired files and libraries and decrease the time to drastically but still slow)

Comment: Can you please provide some more info?  Like:

What is the script?
Does it run fast on linux/mac?
How many libs do you have?
Is the script running your ruby, or maybe jruby?

Comment: I updated the question. I'm not a ruby person myself, I don't know what jruby is, this is plain ruby application. Script is some massive application, which loads lots of plugins onstartup.

Comment: At least post all of the require lines at the top of your script.  There is likely something in there that is causing the slowdown. 30 seconds is waaay too long for things to load.  Something is likely trying to do some sort of network communication and is timing out.

Comment: @Aarron actually by disabling all unrequired library loads (stuff I don't use) it's now about 1.5 seconds with cygwin ruby and 4 seconds with windows ruby. But I'm looking for further optimisation.

Comment: Are you requiring any gems?  We can't help you if we don't know what you are loading.

Comment: I think I do, I'm not sure how can I check it? Script looks like requiring everything in the world :) Actually I did even defrag the library folder which speed it up about 0.5 second :)

Comment: At the very least, update your question with a code snippet of the require lines from your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the script uses rubygems? (It'll say require "rubygems" if so)

You could try installing minigems (gem install minigems) and then use minigems instead of rubygems - should speed things up a little.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no way to compile a ruby script. What sort of stuff is this script loading/doing?

You're right, 30 seconds is quite long. Is this script making calls out to the web or databases that are very expensive? It's hard to believe that libraries would take so long to load

... I just noticed the comments and saw that you got it down to 1-4 seconds...that's very good, especially when coming down from 30. Other comments are right, please post the requires at the top of the script